# If I flush my hot water tank without unplugging the recirculating pump, Will it cause the pump to fail?

Tags: hot-water

If I flush my hot water tank without unplugging the recirculating pump, Will it cause the pump to fail? Will the failure happen immediately, or can it fail later over time?

Answer (score 0):

Why take the risk? Unplug it!  I have a HW recirc system and it def. doesn't like no pressure.  So yes, turn it off and depending upon how you flush your HW tank, you may need to bleed it to get it working again. Most have a screw in the middle of the pump that will allow air to escape.

Comment: I had a friend do this and it burned out. I was trying to get clarification if it would burn out immediately or would it take time to burn out

Comment: Thinking more about this, it sounds like your question might be, "have I screwed up because I forgot to unplug my re-circ pump when I flushed my HW tank?"   Fess-up!   LOL...the more accurate the info you provide the better we can help.

Comment: I agree george haha. Wasnt me, it really was a friend of mine.

Comment: Uh huh, is that like walking into an "adult store" and saying I'm buying this for a friend?!  If not, I think you just answered your own question, just unplug the re-circ pump when flushing the HW tank.  Again, depending upon exactly how, you may need to bleed it after you plug it back in to purge any air that may have entered.

Comment: And if it was not purged, would the burn out happen immediately or could it possibly burn out later, like a couple months? Hes trying to get a refund from a plumber that he believes didnt unplug it before flushing. and the plumber is saying if it were to burn out, it would happen immediately. But, he is saying it is now burnt out a couple months later.

Comment: I just don't know about that. I would think the failure would have been immediate, but I"m not sure.  Maybe someone with more plumbing expertise could weigh in here.

Comment: Thanks, George. Greatly appreciate your input!

Comment: It does not have to show the affect of running it without water immediately.  The impeller will be damage, especially in the time frame it takes to purge the tank.  Putting the damaged impeller under load will eventually cause the impeller to fail.  This is a matter of replacing the impeller, not the whole unit.   But then the damage could be extended to the housing which could be deformed from the heat when running dry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't so much with the motor. They are rated for continuous duty and at a specified RPM which it will do whether under load or not. The problem is with the impeller and bearing. They are not designed to operate under no load. The bearings will over heat and the impeller can fracture from excessive vibration. It's unlikely the motor would burn out because of this but the pumping function could/would be compromised over time.

Comment: Why would this be a DV?

Comment: Agreed, JACK. Why a DV?  I also believe in many cases the impeller is plastic which could deform if it got too hot.   I don't know why they get so hot when not under load. The only think I can think of is the pumps need the flow of water for cooling.   I had a well pump failure here one time and lost pressure.  The re-circ pump got quite hot, but didn't fail, thankfully.   So if I ever have to do any plumbing maintenance that requires turning off the water, I'm sure to turn off the re-circ pump first.